# Who is Shankhayana?

Tags: rishi

There is a Grihya Sutra in the name of Shankhayana, so is a Shrauta Sutra.

Who is this Rishi? What is his period and status in the Vaidika practices?

Answer (score 1):

Lord Sankarshana spoke the essence of [Srimad Bhagavata](https://theharekrishnamovement.org/2015/10/06/srimad-bhagavatam-index-part-4/) to Sanatkumara, who explained it to **Shankhayana Muni**. This was then given to Parashara, who explained it to all.

[Chapter 15 of Shankayana Aranyaka](http://hinduonline.co/Scriptures/Aranyaka/ShankhayanaAranyaka.html) gives a long genealogy of spiritual teachers from Brahma down to Shankhayana.

A [shaka of Rig veda](https://archive.org/details/SankhayanaAranyak/sankhayana%20aranyak) is named after Shankhyana. He has written both Grihya Sutras and Shrauta Sutras, as you mention and the links are given below. Shankhayana as a gotra can be found in North India.

As stated in the English translation of the text of the [Grihya Sutra](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/sankhayana-grihya-sutra)

> The Grihya-sutra ascribed to Shankhayana, is based on the first of the
> four Vedas, the Rig-veda in the Bashkala recension, and among the
> Brahmana texts, on the Kaushitaka.

As stated in the English translation of the text of the [Shrauta sutra of Shankhayana](https://archive.org/details/sankhayanasrauta/page/n15/mode/2up)

> Now one of the Shakhas of the Rig Veda is known as Bashkala Shakha.
> Its Kalpa Sutras were authored by the sage Shankhayana.  It is the
> Shrauta Sutra text of this Shakhas, known as as Shankhayana Shrauta
> Sutras, that is translated here.

Comment: I have removed that part of the answer as it was not in the original question. Regarding his pravara, I will check https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.553693. It contains the gotra and pravara of many.

Comment: yes please check it, thank you for the work

Comment: can you also write a simple translation to the other question and some justification regarding Sha and Sa. I will award the bounty to that answer also.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty. I don't think there are two sages with Sha and Sa. I will try to do the transliteration over the weekend. Thank you.